# Is there a way to group regions on a world map for common functionality?

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm new to trying to use mapping, and not finding the kind of documentation I need.  I'm looking at OpenLayers, but open to other solutions.

I have a client that has sales reps with territories worldwide.  Those territories are not country exclusive, there may be more than one rep in a country with territories divided between states/provinces.  I need the map color-coded so the territories are highlighted by sales rep.  OpenLayers at least, looks like it might be the way to go because zooming in on a world map more sharply defines the regions within a country  (zooming in on the US, shows the individual states).

As it stands, I don't know if OpenLayers will support splitting a country on an un-zoomed view, or how to color code any of the territories (many of the example pages for OpenLayers don't seem to work).

Answer (score 1):

If you have your territories as polygons in a JSON-file, you could load them in as a Vector Layer in OpenLayers (given that they are not too large/have too many points) and then style them based on some attribute. But again, this may be overkill, but as I am not certain of your goals (should the user be able to interacting (i.e. click on) the territories?

If you just want to display a zoomable map with color codes territories then I guess it's easier to create a WMS-layer with for instance Geoserver.